# Change Jeninks build status on specific error

Tags: jenkins, docker

i've got a Jenkins job that should simply start a docker container using the Docker plugin.
If the container is stopped, the job runs correctly, but if the container is already running, the build step returns a failure due to an

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotModifiedException
```

error.

This is basically the expected behavior of Jenkins but in my case, i want to set it to unstable to have a more meaningful response for the user.

I tried to add a conditional build step afterwards using TextFinder that scans the console output for the error, but it seems that it isn't executed after the docker build step fails.

Is there a way to change the build status just for this error?

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins, you can add a [Groovy PostBuild Script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) for that job:

```
exceptionTextRegex = '.*com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotModifiedException.*'

if(manager.logContains(exceptionTextRegex)) {
    manager.buildUnstable()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Groovy PoistBuild was indeed the answer, but the script was a little bit bigger:

```
errpattern = ~/com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotModifiedException.*/;
manager.build.logFile.eachLine{ line ->
    errmatcher=errpattern.matcher(line)
    if (errmatcher.find()) {
        manager.build.@result = hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE
    }
}
```